# How to pass Azure Storage connection string to Serilog in code, while reading other settings from appSettings.json?

Tags: serilog, appsettings, serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage

My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Verbose"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console"
        },
        {
            "Name": "AzureBlobStorage",
            "Args": {
                "storageContainerName": "applogs",
                "storageFileName": "{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/log.txt",
                "writeInBatches": "true",
                "period": "0.00:00:15",
                "batchPostingLimit": "10"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I dont have connection string mentioned above, but I want that to be injected in code, while creating the LoggerConfiguration, like this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
            *<-- set the azure blob storage connection string here -->*
            .CreateLogger();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I solved it by adding this line of code before creating the LoggerConfiguration above: builder.Configuration["Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:connectionString"] = "connection string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding this line of code before creating the LoggerConfiguration above:

```
builder.Configuration["Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:connectionString"] = "connection string"
```